# How to get xml attribute using JAXB

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

this is my xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <organization>
      <bank>
        <description>aaa</description>
        <externalkey>123</externalkey>
        <property name="pName" value="1234567890" />
      </bank>
   </organization>
```

I used JAXB and unmarshall for this xml and I can get description and externalkey. But I cannot get property name with value.

- This is my java class for unmarshall:

  ```
  JAXBContext jb = JAXBContext.newInstance(Organization.class);
  Unmarshaller um = jb.createUnmarshaller();
  Organization org = (Organization) um.unmarshal(new File("\\upload\\bank999999.xml"));
  System.out.println(org.getBank().getDescription());
  System.out.println(org.getBank().getExternalkey());
  ```
- Organization.java

  ```
  @XmlRootElement
  public class Organization {
  Bank bank = new Bank();

  public Bank getBank() {
    return bank;
  }

  public void setBank(Bank bank) {
   this.bank = bank;
  }
  }
  ```
- Bank.java

  ```
  @XmlRootElement
  public class Bank {
   private String description;
   private String externalkey;
   private String property;

  //..GETTER and SETTER
  }
  ```

  How can I get property name and value? Thank u

Comment: show your Organization class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Bank**

You need to change the `property` property from a `String` to a domain object.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bank {
    private String description;
    private String externalkey;
    private Property property;
}
```

**Property**

Then your `Property` object would look something like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Property {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlAtrribute
    private String value;

}
```

Comment: I can get property name and value using org.getBank().getProperty().getName(). How can I get prop value like that : org.getBank().getProperty().getValue("pName")

Comment: @kamal - You are looking for properties to correspond to a `java.util.Map`?

Comment: Yes. How to do it? do u have u any suggestions?

Comment: I'm waiting. Thank u for your attention

Comment: @kamal - The following article will help you get going mapping to Map:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html